# What does "the apricot and black humid evening" mean?

Tags: adjectives, literature, colors

> *Mes fenêtres!* Hanging above blotched sunset and welling night, grinding my teeth, I would crowd all the demons of my desire against
>   the railing of a throbbing balcony: it would be ready to take off
>   ***in the apricot and black humid evening***; did take off—whereupon the lighted image would move and Eve would revert to a rib, and there
>   would be nothing in the window but an obese partly clad man reading
>   the paper.

The quote comes from *Lolita* by Nabokov. Does ***apricot*** signify the apricot colour? Nabokov used ***apricot*** to signify the colour in other parts of *Lolita*. I can very well imagine that sunsets are of apricot colour (and then black nights come), yet the sentence in question sounds strange to me because of ***apricot*** and ***black*** being so close to each other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because interpretation of literature is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

In the Russian version of the novel, which was translated by the author himself, it's literally said:

> в абрикосовую **мглу** влажного вечера

His use of the word **абрикосовый** (abrikosovy) indeed indicates the **apricot** color and nothing else, but he doesn't use the adjective **black**, using instead the noun **мгла** (mgla) which can be translated as: "darkness, murk, blackness, haze, mist". It's quite commonly used to describe late twilight or fog, with a connotation of it being hard to see through. It also implies humid air.

Answer (score 2):

The author might be referring to -

---

## Twilight

> : *the light from the sky between full night and sunrise or between sunset and full night produced by diffusion of sunlight through the atmosphere and its dust.*

---

That takes care of an apricot-colored sunset mixed with a black night on a wet (humid) evening.

---

**EDIT**

A specific twilight for use in this context -

## Nautical twilight

> Nautical twilight is the second twilight phase. Both the horizon and
> the brighter stars are usually visible at this time, making it
> possible to navigate at sea.
>
> [image]

([timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/nautical-twilight.html))

Comment: To be pedantic, probably [civil twilight](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/civil-twilight.html), or [a bit before](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/golden-hour.html)

Comment: @marcellothearcane - I think "*nautical twilight*" would suit this context (more). Or does it? See the above image.

Comment: Depends on your apricots.

Comment: Is that a no? I mean, you *can* see some "apricot" color at the bottom, and darkness at the top, indicating the clear transition from sunset to night. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: This is venturing in POB territory! I'm sure it's fine, I was being silly :)